# How to grow points in PCL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, image-processing, computer-vision, point-cloud-library

I have a set of 3D point cloud and I need to grow the points. By that, I mean I want those points to acquiere some diameter. If possible, I would like to grow points like squares, not circles. This is the first step to a detection algorithm. Now I have 3D points but I could convert them into 2D if needed.

Here's an image trying to explain what I want to achieve. That is, given a point (or a set of points) expand them.

[image]

Thank you, Alex.

Answer (score 1):

You need Dilate filter.

If your cloud is set as array of bool, where true represents the point and false - the emptiness, the size of your cloud is [width x height x depth] and the size of array is width * height * depth:

```
std::vector<bool> mask(width * height * depth);
```

point [x,y,z] is represented by value mask[x + y * width + z * width * height]

Here is a code example to expand each true value in volume (you call Dialte3D function):

```
void DilateDirection(std::vector<bool> &mask, int dimension1, int dimension2, int dilateDimension3, 
                     int dim1offset, int dim2offset, int dim3offset, int radius)
{
  for (int k = 0; k < dimension2; k++)
    for (int j = 0; j < dimension1; j++)
    {
      int r = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < dilateDimension3; i++)
      {
        if (mask[i * dim3offset + j * dim1offset + k * dim2offset])  //start expanding
          r = radius + 1;
        else
          r--;
        if (r > 0)
          mask[i * dim3offset + j * dim1offset + k * dim2offset] = true; //expand in + direction
      }
      r = 0;
      for (int i = dilateDimension3 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      {
        if (mask[i * dim3offset + j * dim1offset + k * dim2offset]) //start expanding
          r = radius + 1;
        else
          r--;
        if (r > 0)
          mask[i * dim3offset + j * dim1offset + k * dim2offset] = true; //expand in - direction
      }
    }
}

void Dilate3D(std::vector<bool> &mask, int width, int height, int depth, int radius)
{
  DilateDirection(mask, height, depth, width, width, width * height, 1, radius); //dilate by X
  DilateDirection(mask, width, depth, height, 1, width * height, width, radius); //dilate by Y
  DilateDirection(mask, width, height, depth, 1, width, width * height, radius); //dilate by Z
}
```